# Eigenvalue and Eigenvector proof of matrix polynomial

Tags: matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a polynomial
$$f(s) = s^m+a_1s^{m-1}+\cdots +a_m$$
and a square matrix $A$. Prove: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with corresponding eigenvector $x$, then $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(A)$ with corresponding eigenvector $x$. (Recall that $f(A)$ is the matrix
$A^m + a_1 A^{m-1}+ \cdots +a_m I.$)

Comment: @Andej Bauer thanks for editing, still learning how to use Latex.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e.,
$$A x=\lambda x$$
then
$$A^k x=A^{k-1}(A x)=A^{k-1}(\lambda x)=\lambda A^{k-1} x$$
and by a simple induction we have
$$A^{k} x=\lambda^k x$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is a polynomial and $Av = \lambda v$, then $p(A)v = \sum_k p_k A^k v = \sum_k p_k \lambda^k v =p(\lambda) v$.

The result is true for more general functions than polynomials (see the spectral mapping theorem for example).

Answer (score 0):

Multiply $f(A)$ by $x$ and see what you get. Compare it with what you want to prove.